# Problem using click event in angular 8 directive

Tags: angular8, directive

Im new to Angular and I have a directive that displays a dicom image and use cornerstone tools (Zoom and length) using cornerstoneJs librarie. The image is diplayed but the problem is when I want to associate each tool to two input radio so that the user can select and choose which tool to use. To do this, I created 2 functions each one activates one cornerstone tools which I associated to each input radio, but the problem is that only the first function is executed when I click on the two input radio.

cornerstone.directive.ts :

```
 @Output() myClick1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() myClick2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])

 onClick1(event) {      
      cornerstoneTools.addTool(cornerstoneTools[`${'Length'}Tool`]);
      cornerstoneTools.setToolActive('Length', { mouseButtonMask: 1 } ); 
      this.myClick1;
 }

 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])

 onClick2(event) {
      cornerstoneTools.addTool(cornerstoneTools[`${'Zoom'}Tool`]);
      cornerstoneTools.setToolActive('Zoom', { mouseButtonMask: 1 } ); 
      this.myClick2;
 }
```

viewer.html :

```
<input  type="radio" class="left" name="tool" (myClick1)="onClick1($event)"  appCornerstone> Length
  
<input  type="radio" class="left" name="tool" (myClick2)="onClick2($event))" appCornerstone> Zoom
```

The problem is when I select length tool it is enabled, but when I select zoom the length tool sill enabled and the zoom tool is not activated.

Thank u so much !

Comment: The last function*. I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools/issues/1018. I didn't try it but I think this will work for you.

```
 @Output() myClick1: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() myClick2: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])

 onClick1(event) {      
      cornerstoneTools.addTool(cornerstoneTools[`${'Length'}Tool`]);
      cornerstoneTools.setToolActive('Length', { mouseButtonMask: 1 } ); 
      cornerstoneTools.setToolDisabled('Zoom');  
      this.myClick1;
 }

 @HostListener('click', ['$event'])

 onClick2(event) {
      cornerstoneTools.addTool(cornerstoneTools[`${'Zoom'}Tool`]);
      cornerstoneTools.setToolActive('Zoom', { mouseButtonMask: 1 } ); 
      cornerstoneTools.setToolDisabled('Length');
      this.myClick2;
 }
```